# how to call intent.getSourceBounds();

Tags: android, methods, android-intent

i'm trying to call intent.getSourceBounds(); method but it gives me error and it propose me Add cast to 'intent'. I saw a lot of codes that use this method what should i do in order to call this method?

Comment: Please include the code that is causing the problem, and the full error that you're getting otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: You need to put more detail into your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked for the API level and i saw that i need to use at least API level 7 in order to use this method, so the problem is that i'm using API level 5 at this moment.